# Communication Between DialogFragment and Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am trying to pass information from my alert dialog to my second fragment (I am using tabbed activity layout).

I want to pass information from alert dialog to fragment when I click on my ImageView, but my app keep crashing until I implement my interface inside MainActivity.java. My main mission here is to open alert dialog which contains several buttons. When I click first button I want to print "Test br 3" but it does not work inside my Fragment, it only works inside my MainActivity.java where method prints "Test br 2".

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExercisesAlertDialog.DataTransfer {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    }

    @Override
    public void ApplyData() {
       System.out.println("Test br 2");
    }
```

My Fragment

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment implements ExercisesAlertDialog.DataTransfer {


      ImageView plusbtn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);

        plusbtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.plusbtn);


        plusbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ExercisesDialog();
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

public void ExercisesDialog()
{
    ExercisesAlertDialog exercisesAlertDialog = new ExercisesAlertDialog();
    exercisesAlertDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Exercises Dialog");
}

    @Override
    public void ApplyData() {
        System.out.println("Test br 3");
    }
```

My Alert Dialog

```
public class ExercisesAlertDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    ImageButton one, two;
    private DataTransfer listener;
    public int first;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_custom_menu, null);
        builder.setView(v);
        builder.setTitle("Choose your Workout");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dismiss();
            }
        });

        one = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.first);
        two = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.second);

one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        first = 1;
        if(first ==1)
        {
listener.ApplyData();
        }


    }
});


        return builder.create();
    }


    public interface DataTransfer
    {
        void ApplyData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (DataTransfer) context;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(toString() + "Must implement DataTransfer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For that setup, you would need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` in the `show()` call. Then change the line in `onAttach()` to `listener = (DataTransfer) getParentFragment();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() in the show() call. Second thing is onAttach() to listener = (DataTransfer) getParentFragment(); instead of context.